# Guarantee Unique objects in factory using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, move, factory, unique-ptr

I came across the following code for a factory.

- `T::create(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` returns a pointer to an object created dynamically. So basically if two objects have the same address then they are the same.
- `unique_ptr` guarantees that a single `unique_ptr` container has ownership of the held pointer. This means that you can't make copies of a unique_ptr.

---

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class PoolFactory {
 public:
  template <typename... Args>
  T *getInstance(Args... args) {
    _createdItems.push_back(
        std::unique_ptr<T>(T::create(std::forward<Args>(args)...)));
    return _createdItems.back().get();
  }
  ~PoolFactory() = default;

 public:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> _createdItems;
};
```

---

## Question

Suppose we are trying to insert an object that already exists in the vector. Since we are using a factory and **IF** the object already exists we just want to retrieve it. How will that archtitecture that contains move semantics guarantee that behavior?

Comment: The premise of the question doesn't make much sense to me. No two pointers in the vector will point at the same object in a well-formed program. You seem to understand it yourself, as you preface your question with it.

Comment: You are conflating two different notions of "unique" here. There is object identity (basically the pointer) and object equality (in your case, "created with the same set of `args`"). Having unique objects in the sense of identity is trivial (as @StoryTeller remarked). Having unique objects in the sense of equality would require some way to _check_ equality (based on the provided `args`) - this is what the current answer is pointing out.

Comment: Also, it is unclear why you worry about move semantics. You are returning a pointer, the ownership stays with the factory. Therefore, no objects have to/should be moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpreting this code, in this factory your objects are identified by `getInstance` arguments. The interface also suggests that the callers know both `T` and its constructor arguments, so that they can construct `T` themselves.

The only use for this factory is to make each object a singleton.

You need a mapping `(args...) -> object`, rather than an array, so that first you look up an existing object using `args...` and create the object if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Technically a vector can be a mapping `(args...) -> object` (and there are situations where it is the best mapping). I guess you just meant "...rather than a vector of `object`s" or similar?

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten the "uniqueness" of `std::unique_ptr<T>` backwards. There is not a magic mechanism such that when you create a `std::unique_ptr<T>` somehow it checks all the currently existing `std::unique_ptr<T>` and does something different if one owns the same pointer value.

Instead, it is assumed that you have previously `new`ed a `T *` and construct a `std::unique_ptr<T>` from it, or call `std::make_unique<T>` to `new` a `T` and wrap it in a `unique_ptr<T>` for you. If that assumption is not the case, and the `std::unique_ptr<T>` is destroyed, your program's behaviour is undefined.

The prohibition on copying then assures you that `delete` is called *exactly once*, and often with no additional effort on your part (i.e. the pointee's lifetime is exactly the same as the pointer's lifetime)